# Real-Time webapp / Akka actor notifying the websocket connection to send information to client

Tags: web-applications, websocket, akka, actor, playframework-2.2

I use Play Framework 2.2.1 with Scala.

The scenario I want to achieve is:

As soon as a new registered user logs in the for the first time, some interesting updates must be made into the database.
It would be a pretty long-running process (about few seconds).
What I want is to notify the user (front-end so) when all the updates are made, and that he can now benefit of these newly created links (no matter what the updates could bring to him in details).

I've thought about detaching an Akka actor in my controller in order to process the needed logic for the different updates and execute them into the database.
Indeed, the database access is a blocking IO in my case.

My main question is how to benefit of websocket to notify the user only when this long-running task is completed.

Does a mechanism exist to notify my already established websocket connection that an actor has just finished its job ?

Comment: Do you encounter a particular issue while trying to push a message through your already established WS connection?

Comment: Actually, I'm currently studying the needed architecture to do the trick, and I would like to know a common way to do the trick, since it's not easily revealed in the actual Play documentation. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWebSockets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?:

In your controller, when the user first makes the request, call the method that is going to execute the different operations, since these are blocking, wrap the DB calls in a given actor, then instead of calling a simple method to get the result, you should be able to ask the actor to do the operations, this `ask` method (cf [Akka doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html)) will return a future.

This future would then be sent to a given actor that is holding references to the different connections (meanwhile the controller returns a Result, Ok...), this actor should then listen for the state of the future, in case it's successful (onSuccess), push a message using the appropriate connection to the appropriate user. The out [enumerator](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Enumerators) can be retrieved and saved when first creating the WS connection, a basic approach that comes to mind is that you can keep them in a map with the user id as key. You can then use these enumerators to push messages to the clients.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to mean that database access is blocking, not non-blocking. But it should not change the mechanism. A lot of article deals with a connection to websocket provoked by the client, I am interested with the reverse. So you said that I could keep the reference to the websocket connection inside my actor, how? According to the doc, a websocket is "isolated" in a REST call (controller's method) and only reachable from its `ws://` url.

Comment: Yes, but when creating the connection you are also returning an out enumerator, this is the object that should be used to push messages to the user. I updated my answer to address your remarks.

Comment: Your solution does make sense. What is the benefit of using two actors instead of one (updating database and notifying socket)? => no matter, I'm figuring out, the second actor is a durable listener, the first one a temporary one, needed to not block the main play request's thread.

Comment: It is just better to create different objects to handle different tasks, maybe in the future you would want to separate the code interacting with DB from other logic... Also, it is prettier to separate things that execute different tasks IMO.

Comment: Okay, I totally agree, I wanted to make sure that I didn't missed a particular Akka actor concept, since I'm just discovering it :) Thank you